# Create a grid form to add components and move them to specific locations

Tags: c#, grid, draggable, drag, moveable

I am using c# with windows forms and I would like to create a grid field where I can drag components to. When added, it can be dragged around that grid and place it at some location which aligns it automatically.
A very long time ago I have used such software from Syntellect which works very nice. But I am wondering how to create such grid.
In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CoOP6X7yxA) you can see what i'm trying to create which you see at about 4:00.

Tried some with the listview but that didn't give me the results which I want.